# TypeORM delete using WHERE with OR operator using Repository

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, nestjs, typeorm

I have a `Repository` class with which I would like to delete Entities in my database using the inherited method `repository.delete()` based on 2 conditions combined via the `OR` operator.

I would to achieve something like that:

```
deleteAllAboOfUser(userId: string): Promise<DeleteResult> {
        return this.delete([
            { followerId: userId},
            {followingId: userId}
        ]);
    }
```

And the generated SQL should look like the following:

```
DELETE FROM subscription WHERE follower_id = 'xxxx' OR following_id = 'xxxx';
```

But it seems to be impossible currently to uses the `OR` condition for the delete, but only the `AND`.

Comment: It's possible to use `OR`. Can you please add your `delete` method?

Answer (score 1):

Checked [documentation](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/repository-api.md#treerepository-api) of a repository API and found that there is no provision to delete based on the `OR` operator.

I think you need to use the query builder to achieve this.